# Interface must contain only keys from an array literal

Tags: typescript

In an HTTP response we have a bunch of keyed sections that get grouped when received in the client and I need to filter based on specific keys in order to group.

I was hoping I could have it so the addition of an item to a specific group would be enforceable on the interface or equivalent type so it isn't overlooked and provides a bit of assistance to someone who probably didn't read the comment.

I've been playing with this on a specific group for profile sections and going back and forth on how it might be implemented, but ultimately thinking it might not be possible:

```
export interface Section {
  statusCode: number;
}

export interface CustomSection extends Section {
  differentKey: string;
}

export const profileSectionKeys = [
  'demographics',
  'collegeCertification',
  'userAccessAgreement',
  'transactions',
  'newSection' // <--- newly added section to the profile group
] as const;

export type ProfileSectionKey = typeof profileSectionKeys[number];

export type IProfileSection = {
  [K in typeof profileSectionKeys[number]]: Section; 
};

export interface ProfileSection { // <--- want to have type error when key is missing
  demographics: CustomSection;
  collegeCertification: CustomSection;
  userAccessAgreement: Section;
  transactions: Section;
  // Missing newSection key!
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/N9EB7N) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: I don't know what `Section`s are so I changed things to `string`s and string literals.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mMMddm) meet your needs?  The error isn't directly on the declaration of `ProfileSection` but it still tells you what's wrong.  If it doesn't meet your needs, could you describe the unsatisfied use case in detail?

Comment: @jcalz sorry a `Section` is just an interface representing an object literal that has a few base keys or it extends `Section` with some extra keys like DemographicSection.  Yes that example definitely works.  So that type wouldn't be used, but provides the assurance.  That's an interesting approach that I'll definitely use.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer explaining it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest thing you could do is just make `ProfileSection` [an `interface` that `extends`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) `IProfileSection`:

```
interface ProfileSection extends IProfileSection {
    demographics: CustomSection;
    collegeCertification: CustomSection;
}
```

This automatically inherits the properties from `IProfileSection` into `ProfileSection`, and if you want to make some of the properties more specific, you can narrow them by redeclaring them, as shown.  So if you don't mention a property, it will just be a `Section`:

```
declare const profileSection: ProfileSection;
profileSection.demographics.differentKey.toUpperCase(); // okay
profileSection.userAccessAgreement.statusCode.toFixed(); // also okay
profileSection.newSection.statusCode.toFixed(); // also okay
```

So there's no chance of accidentally "leaving out" `newSection`.

---

On the other hand, maybe you have a use case whereby you don't want `ProfileSection` to automatically inherit from `IProfileSection`, but you do want to make sure that it is structurally compatible with `IProfileSection`... so it should not leave out any keys and all the properties must be of type `Section` or something narrower.  (I can't actually think of such a use case, but this is what you've asked for, so ‍♂️).

If so, then I don't know of any way to annotate the declaration of `ProfileSection` itself to achieve this.  But you can make a "helper" type that checks `ProfileSection` and provides the requisite error if that constraint is violated.  For example:

```
type CheckProfileSection<T extends IProfileSection =
    ProfileSection> = void
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- if there's an error here then you need to fix ProfileSection below

interface ProfileSection { 
    demographics: CustomSection;
    collegeCertification: CustomSection;
    userAccessAgreement: Section;
    transactions: Section;
    newSection: Section;
}
```

Nobody will ever use `CheckProfileSection` for anything, (it evaluates to `void` no matter what).  Its only purpose is to "watch" `ProfileSection`.  The above compiles without error.  But if I remove `newSection` from `ProfileSection`,

```
interface ProfileSection { 
    demographics: CustomSection;
    collegeCertification: CustomSection;
    userAccessAgreement: Section;
    transactions: Section;
    // newSection: Section;
}
```

then you get this error:

```
type CheckProfileSection<T extends IProfileSection =
    ProfileSection> = void // error!!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Property 'newSection' is missing in type 'ProfileSection'
//  but required in type 'IProfileSection'.
```

So that works as desired.

---

There you go.  Personally I would just write `interface ProfileSection extends IProfileSection`, but the `CheckProfileSection` option also works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQWYB7EyDeAsAFDJnIDOYcYArhQMLYAmEAXMiLQLYBG0AbhIBfEiVCRYiFA3phs3dJhx4IAD0ghmFNBiy4CJcsmbAYMaBHABpCAE8OVKKADmQ4qOIkEuKsgAOUNgwwAA2EEr6ILZ2OgC8yADaRuQA5Kzc2C5QcP4AFsAIFKkANClkqT6h4S4QDNBYIQg0KqXlyKn00ACCCEgUFN3ZEBDcVmBtpGlgOSAUiFHFZVMVIBAA7pGtyAD0O8gAPAC0J5wboXbIcMyszJR6KsjyT3kogcFhKNnYtP4kALpXHQ+OZgdwkMB2fwoAAKQRC4S2uBiyASkOhwQC8M+SOi9goiS4fGg-3BxHRKAAknCPoiHgYEkQVklrMhQE8oRBMe8ERF6XjYoSePwoP9-hxce5hGSQHAxhR-NJkABRDRWO5M4wSaDwJDIGm83HIdSabTIanYunKAya4zkDJZHL5QoUDiyKgKSXtYxVGp1BpmQotXBuuSe-nuYyeYysBChOBQFAgvw8nH8jgGtPWkCR8ipq1RAB0DuyuQKRWLZgsiZs9kL8gAqv5oVAGHAKBAABQASgEu322AA1nA7O183zs4WulBev1BsNRuNC1QaPQmKx69gAGLANQQZg9vt7K6hCjYZBDkdjy0TotrTb85fUOiMFgQTc7vcH3v9k9ni-DqOHhiMQsryoqeoMK8CCDoYXjMhSyBQRgg6ZgWKgHAAKsaapaDoFq0rejxxN65BoURuAAHyosgABu2DAHcx7QEEUAAIRse0x7IAAenx-ECQJhynGYLyWKkOhwKoUCscgryJmJeB2D8Zz7k854hGo+o3ka-ChNg6xcfsyAAH5meZFkWUZZA0i2kIdPeuKpGyOjcMAAyuGyeCIak5FOdZyC8LQYDIImACOtDAImdzsj5BGGvyqSFiBWrgDqSp+fyBDIKRZAlk65aukhYaKBGuXIL6EC1PUUCNEGUShh6pXZrmdrINOs4QAMQyJou4ASmVzLGDMUnzNmRVekN5DHo56a6C17SeO0sbxgpyYheOuIZjpg3GJtj75WWLqVuYli1nYm5Ni2bYdoev6XkBe07ZOHV9F1869WM4BPqur4bvIn77ndx5wKe54PdehG4oWs2TiuL7ru+AO7kDP7MTJ2BQCIIHCEAA)